# How to redirect a .com domain name to .co.uk domain using the htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I need to redirect the domain name: http://mydomain.com to http://mydomain.co.uk

In such a way that anytime a visitor visits the .com he will get redirected to the .co.uk version. Both domain names direct to the same hosting provider.

In addition to that, I need to rewrite the rules to render the sites without the `www.`. 
As in: `mydomain.co.uk` rather than: `www.mydomain.co.uk`.

I am using WordPress. I am looking to learn how to do this from the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As everything is being redirected to `http://mydomain.com.uk`, there is no need to remove the `www` from `http://www.mydomain.com` when present.

You may try this at the .htaccess file at root directory of `mydomain.com`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)  http://mydomain.com.uk/$1     [R=301,L,NC]
```

To remove the `www` from `http://www.mydomain.com.uk` you have to put a set of rules in one .htaccess file at root directory of that site. Something like this should work:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.mydomain\.com\.uk  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)     http://mydomain.com.uk/$1    [R=301,L,NC]
```